# How do I become a Saddhanussari or Dhammanussari and know if I have attained it?

Tags: stream-entry

How do I become a Saddhanussari or Dhammanussari and how do I know if I have attained it?

I think that the question above is clear enough. Just to add I have read their descriptions in the Suttas but from them, the answer to these questions are still unclear. He describes them as such:

[MN 70](https://suttacentral.net/mn70/en/sujato)

> And what person is a **follower of the teachings** (**dhammanussari**)? It’s a person who
> doesn’t have direct meditative experience of the peaceful liberations
> that are formless, transcending form. Nevertheless, having seen with
> wisdom, some of their defilements have come to an end. And they accept
> the teachings proclaimed by the Realized One after considering them
> with a degree of wisdom. And they have the following qualities: the
> faculties of faith, energy, mindfulness, immersion, and wisdom. This
> person is called a follower of the teachings. I say that this
> mendicant also still has work to do with diligence. Why is that?
> Thinking: ‘Hopefully this venerable will frequent appropriate
> lodgings, associate with good friends, and control their faculties.
> Then they might realize the supreme culmination of the spiritual path
> in this very life, and live having achieved with their own insight the
> goal for which gentlemen rightly go forth from the lay life to
> homelessness.’ Seeing this fruit of diligence for this mendicant, I
> say that they still have work to do with diligence.
>
> And what person is
> a **follower by faith** (**saddhanussari**)? It’s a person who doesn’t have direct meditative
> experience of the peaceful liberations that are formless, transcending
> form. Nevertheless, having seen with wisdom, some of their defilements
> have come to an end. And they have a degree of faith and love for the
> Realized One. And they have the following qualities: the faculties of
> faith, energy, mindfulness, immersion, and wisdom. This person is
> called a follower by faith. I say that this mendicant also still has
> work to do with diligence. Why is that? Thinking: ‘Hopefully this
> venerable will frequent appropriate lodgings, associate with good
> friends, and control their faculties. Then they might realize the
> supreme culmination of the spiritual path in this very life, and live
> having achieved with their own insight the goal for which gentlemen
> rightly go forth from the lay life to homelessness.’ Seeing this fruit
> of diligence for this mendicant, I say that they still have work to do
> with diligence.

How does one 'accept the teachings proclaimed by the Realized One after considering them with a degree of wisdom.'? Or 'have a degree of faith and love for the Realized One'? And how does one know that one has fulfilled this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> There are five things that can turn out in two ways in the here-&-now. Which five? Conviction, liking, unbroken tradition, reasoning by analogy, & an agreement through pondering views. Now some things are firmly held in conviction and yet vain, empty, & false. Some things are not firmly held in conviction, and yet they are genuine, factual, & unmistaken. Some things are well-liked... truly an unbroken tradition... well-reasoned... Some things are well-pondered and yet vain, empty, & false. Some things are not well-pondered, and yet they are genuine, factual, & unmistaken.
>
> [Canki Sutta: With Canki (MN 95)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/mn/mn.095x.than.html)

> At Savatthi. "Monks, the eye is inconstant, changeable, alterable. The
> ear... The nose... The tongue... The body... The mind is inconstant,
> changeable, alterable.
>
> "One who has conviction & belief that these phenomena are this way is
> called a faith-follower: one who has entered the orderliness of
> rightness, entered the plane of people of integrity, transcended the
> plane of the run-of-the-mill. He is incapable of doing any deed by
> which he might be reborn in hell, in the animal womb, or in the realm
> of hungry shades. He is incapable of passing away until he has realized the fruit of stream-entry.
>
> "One who, after pondering with a modicum of discernment, has accepted
> that these phenomena are this way is called a Dhamma-follower: one who
> has entered the orderliness of rightness, entered the plane of people
> of integrity, transcended the plane of the run-of-the-mill. He is
> incapable of doing any deed by which he might be reborn in hell, in
> the animal womb, or in the realm of hungry shades. He is incapable of passing away until he has realized the fruit of stream-entry.
>
> Hearing the Dhamma, he remembers it. Remembering it, he penetrates the meaning of those dhammas. Penetrating the meaning, he comes to an agreement through pondering those dhammas. There being an agreement through pondering those dhammas, desire arises. With the arising of desire, he becomes willing. Willing, he contemplates (lit: "weighs," "compares"). Contemplating, he makes an exertion. Exerting himself, he both realizes the ultimate meaning of the truth with his body and sees by penetrating it with discernment.
>
> "One who knows and sees that these phenomena are this way is called a
> stream-enterer, steadfast, never again destined for states of woe,
> headed for self-awakening."
>
> [Cakkhu Sutta: The Eye (SN 25.1)](https://www.accesstoinsight.org/tipitaka/sn/sn25/sn25.001.than.html)

Comment: Nice, but which Sutta is this from?

Comment: Cakku sutta and canki sutta. I mixed them for your convenience

Comment: It's noteworthy to me how these 3 discourses semantically target the same development in different expression, good to draw out meaning for the different phrases.

Comment: Rūpa/Dhatu Sutta  (SN 25:2/9)
Near Sāvatthī. “Monks, forms are inconstant, changeable, alterable. Sounds.… Aromas.… Flavors.… Tactile sensations.… Ideas are inconstant, changeable, alterable.…At Savatthi. "Monks, the earth property is inconstant, changeable, alterable. The liquid property... The fire property... The wind property... The space property... The consciousness property is inconstant, changeable, alterable.
"One who has conviction & belief that these phenomena are this way is called a faith-follower...

Answer (score 0):

I would assume these 2 followers, faith and dharma followers are on the path to sotapanna.
Quite simply judge your own mind, are you following the dharma because you believe (faith follower) that the noble truths are true and the 8fold path leads to liberation, or have you experienced some fruit of the practice, experienced defilements lessen or cease and are following because of your own experience (dharma follower)